# Google Cloud Function -- Convert BigQuery Data to Gzip (Compressed) Json then Load to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

*For context, this script is largely based on the one found in this guide from Google: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-extract-table-json#bigquery_extract_table_json-nodejs

I have the below script which is functioning. However, it writes a normal JSON file to cloud storage. To be a bit more optimized for file transfer and storage,I wanted to use `const {pako} = require('pako');` to compress the files before loading.

I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this, unfortunately, after numerous attempts.

Anyone have any ideas?

**I'm assuming it has something to do with the options in `.extract(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), options);`, but again, pretty lost in how to figure this out unfortunately...

Any help would be appreciated! :)

**The intent of this function is:

1. It is a Google Cloud function
2. It gets data from BigQuery
3. It writes that data in JSON format to Cloud Storage

My goal is to integrate Pako (or another means of compression) to compress the JSON files to gzip format prior to moving into storage.

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const storage = new Storage();

functions.http('extractTableJSON', async (req, res) => {
    // Exports my_dataset:my_table to gcs://my-bucket/my-file as JSON.
    // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-extract-table-json#bigquery_extract_table_json-nodejs

    const DateYYYYMMDD = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");

    const datasetId = "dataset-1";
    const tableId = "example";
    const bucketName = "domain.appspot.com";
    const filename = `/cache/${DateYYYYMMDD}/example.json`;

    // Location must match that of the source table.
    const options = {
        format: 'json',
        location: 'US',
    };

    // Export data from the table into a Google Cloud Storage file
    const [job] = await bigquery
        .dataset(datasetId)
        .table(tableId)
        .extract(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename), options);

    console.log(`Job ${job.id} created.`);
    res.send(`Job ${job.id} created.`);
    // Check the job's status for errors
    const errors = job.status.errors;
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        res.send(errors);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gzip compress the result, simply use [that option](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/6e82485e74042b8c0ad1bad7f14680f97916eaa7/src/table.ts#L127)

```
   // Location must match that of the source table.
    const options = {
        format: 'json',
        location: 'US',
        gzip: true,
    };
```

Job done ;)

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but on frontend I’m using pako to decompress the files and it doesn’t seem to work with whatever compression algo google uses for this. Do you know how you could uncompress the files you compress  with this out of the box method google offers?

Comment: Absolutely not stupid because something was obvious to me, and by testing it didn't work. I tested with the export data statement, not by code. I would like to check with you if it's the same "issue" by code on your side before opening a bug in the Google Cloud bug tracker. Can you go to your Cloud Storage, pick one exported file in GZIP format and go to the metadata tab and tell me if the content-encoding is set to `gzip` or not. Thanks!

Comment: Created a repo with a bunch of things including an example json export from Bigquery (which is the format i'm looking to accomplish; except compressed). then, the formats (both compressed and uncompressed) im getting out of the cloud function - neither of which look correct. I've added a README with all the details + the code itself: https://github.com/jmelm93/bq-cf-to-gs-json-issue

Comment: For some additional context - i just pulled the data for this from a 3rd party resource, so none of it is private. Feel free to share / use as needed if you are looking into troubleshooting! Really appreciate the help - have been trying to troubleshoot this for longer than I'd like to admit... :)

Comment: Added a "solution" to reformat the response to a proper json array. not the most ideal thing in the world, but it works.  Let me know if you figure out how to avoid this and ensure the initial object built by the job is a proper json array.

Comment: Ah, you are looking for an array of rows!!! Ok, you can't have it out of the box. BigQuery export JSONL file (JSON Line, with 1 valid JSON per line, representing a row in BQ)

Comment: Ah... Okay, I'll update my answer to explain that. I was expecting a JSON array back - which is where my confusion was coming in. Not going to lie, I've never seen a response like that before - but I'm also very new to development

Comment: Thanks again for the help - I just added a bunch of details (some of which are likely beyond the scope of the initial question I had, but figured they'd still be helpful) in to the answer I supplied above.

Answer (score 0):

From guillaume blaquiere `Ah, you are looking for an array of rows!!! Ok, you can't have it out of the box. BigQuery export JSONL file (JSON Line, with 1 valid JSON per line, representing a row in BQ) –  guillaume blaquiere`

Turns out that I had a misunderstanding of the expected output. I was expecting a JSON Array, whereas the output is individual JSON lines, as Guillaume mentioned above.

So, if you're looking for a JSON Array output, you can still use the helper found below to convert the output, but turns out, that was in fact the expected output and I was mistakenly thinking it was inaccurate (sorry - I'm new ...)

```
// step #1: Use the below options to export to compressed JSON (as per guillaume blaquiere's note) 
const options = {
  format: 'json',
  location: 'US',
  gzip: true,
};

// step #2 (if you're looking for a JSON Array): you can use the below helper function to convert the response. 
function convertToJsonArray(text: string): any {
  // wrap in array and add comma at end of each line and remove last comma
  const wrappedText = `[${text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ",").slice(0, -1)}]`;
  const jsonArray = JSON.parse(wrappedText);
  return jsonArray;
}
```

For reference / in case it's helpful, i created this function that'll handle both compressed and uncompressed JSON that's returned.

The application of this is that i'm writing the BigQuery table to JSON in cloud storage to act as a "cache" then requesting that file from a React app and using the below to parse the file in the React app for use on frontend.

```
import pako from 'pako';

function convertToJsonArray(text: string): any {
  const wrappedText = `[${text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ",").slice(0, -1)}]`;
  const jsonArray = JSON.parse(wrappedText);
  return jsonArray;
}


async function getJsonData(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const Uint8Arr = pako.inflate(arrayBuffer);
    const arrayBuf  = new TextDecoder().decode(Uint8Arr);
    const jsonArray = convertToJsonArray(arrayBuf);
    return jsonArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error unzipping file, trying to parse as is.", error)
    const parsedBuffer = new TextDecoder().decode(arrayBuffer);
    const jsonArray = convertToJsonArray(parsedBuffer);
    return jsonArray; 
  }
}
```

Comment: It works as long as the BigQuery response can stay in memory.

Comment: FYI for those that read this answer. JSONL/JSON Lines is a website. `NDJSON` is the name and the standard for newline delimited JSON.